# MVC generates a text box with 'time' type in development, but reverts to 'text' upon deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a property in my model:

```
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}")]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime? CompanyFromTime { set; get; }
```

Note the DataType. When I run this locally in IIS, and view it in chrome, I see the HTML5 time editor which is correct, this is the html that is emitted:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" id="CompanyFromTime" name="CompanyFromTime" type="time" value="">
```

When I deploy this solution to live and view it in chrome, I DO NOT get the html editor but I get a plain text box that jquery seems to try to validate as a datetime:

```
<input class="text-box single-line input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field CompanyToTime must be a date." id="CompanyToTime" name="CompanyToTime" type="text" value="00:00">
```

The output is significantly different! It's almost as if the DataType is being ignored and the default validation is treating this as a DateTime.

Does anyone know why That DataType might be ignored?

Comment: Did you check with same browser in both  environment ?

Comment: All the browsers, that don't support new html5 types, they fallback to text type, so may be that is the reason. mvc is doing its job fairly. check in other MODERN browsers.

Comment: out of curiosity, do you lave latest MVC 4 installed on server? As this feature is only available in MVC 4 if i am not mistaking.

Comment: Yes, used the same browser in both environments.

I am deploying mvc4 from my bin folder - AspNetMvc.4.0.10906.0 which I am getting from NuGet and deploying as copy to local upon publish.

Am going to try to install it on the server anyway because it at least rules that out!

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity, do you lave latest MVC 4 installed on server? As this feature is only available in MVC 4 if i am not mistaking.

You might also want to give a shot at [Mvc Html5 Toolkit](http://mvchtml5.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Installed MVC4 again and all started working as expected.